# Tracking Google Tag Manager publish events

Tags: google-tag-manager

How would I detect a Google Tag Manager publish event and send that to an external system?

I am trying to pinpoint effects of specific tag changes for certain properties and correlate them in a graph the way I might do with a new GitHub tag being created.

I've looked thru documentation but have not uncovered anything yet specifically for this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could user [container notifications](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/9713667?hl=en) to have an email sent to some service that processes the mail and stores the information.

Or you can use the API, retrieve the [container fingerprint](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/api/v2/reference/accounts/containers) and compare it against a stored version of the fingerprint to see if it has changed. This would require you do implement some sort of polling in the API script to check every *n* minutes for changes.